# How does one strip text between two delimiters including empty lines?

Tags: python, python-2.7, delimiter

I am trying to remove text between these two delimiters: '<' & '>'. I am reading email content and then writing that content to a .txt file.I get a lot of junk between those two delimiters including whitespace between lines in my .txt file. How do I get rid of this? Below is what my script has been reading from the data written to my .txt file:

```
 First Name</td>

                <td bgcolor='white' style='padding:5px

 !important;'>Austin</td>

                </tr><tr>

                <td bgcolor='#f9f9f9' style='padding:5px !important;'

 valign='top' width=170>Last Name</td>
```

Below is my current code for reading from the .txt file which strips empty lines:

```
    # Get file contents
    fd = open('emailtext.txt','r')
    contents = fd.readlines()
    fd.close()

    new_contents = []

    # Get rid of empty lines
    for line in contents:
        # Strip whitespace, should leave nothing if empty line was just       "\n"
        if not line.strip():
            continue
        # We got something, save it
        else:
            new_contents.append(line)

    for element in new_contents:
        print element
```

Here is what is expected:

```
 First Name     Austin      


 Last Name      Jones
```

Comment: Can you post your expected output for your example please?

Comment: Ditto @Farhan.K , but add a few input/expected/got doohickeys (Technical term)

Comment: First Name  Austin  


Last Name  Jones

Answer (score 0):

```
markup = '<td bgcolor='#f9f9f9' style='padding:5px !important;'

 valign='top' width=170>Last Name</td>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup)
soup.get_text()
```

you can use `BeautifulSoup`

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a regex and the [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) function:

```
import re
print re.sub(r'<.*?>', '', text, re.DOTALL)
```

Even if the suggestion *"do not use custom parser to parse HTML"* is always valid.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the result of your line.strip() to a variable and add that to your other content. Otherwise you will just save the unstripped line.

```
for line in contents:

    line = line.strip()

    if not line:
        continue
    # We got something, save it
    else:
        new_contents.append(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to remove all HTML tags from a text. You could do that *by hand* but tags can be complex and even use multiple lines.

My advise would be to use BeautifulSoup which is specially written to process xml and html:

```
import bs4

# extract content... then
new_content = bs4.BeautifoulSoup(content, 'html.parser').text
print new_content
```

bs4 module has been extensively tested, copes with many corner cases and highly reduce your own code...

Comment: I will try this out. Thanks for your input.